# How to open a new window on iphone's standalone (fullscreen) mode

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile-safari, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
function goToPage() {
    var pageUrl = 'http://www.google.com/';
    window.open(pageUrl);
}
</script>
<div id="installBtn" onclick="goToPage()">go to page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected action is: when touch the div, a new window opens.
This code works great in the iPhone's safari.

But when I tap "+" -> "Add to Home Screen", and press "go to page", no window is opened, and the page loads in the same screen.

How to force, *by javascript*, a new window to open in the standalone mode?

Answer (score 1):

The below question does mention a possible JavaScript solution out of the top voted answers, which constructs the anchor element and dispatches the 'click' event on it.

Question: [Force link to open in mobile safari from a web app with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7930001/1441046)
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833025/1441046

Alternatively if you can use an anchor element (I know you asked how to do it in JavaScript) you can do the following:

```
<a id="installBtn" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">go to page</a>
```

Other related questions:

[iPhone window.open(url, '_blank') does not open links in mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436676/iphone-window-openurl-blank-does-not-open-links-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Doesn't work when requesting it from html, only from JS.

```
window.open('[url]','_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use childbrowser to open in the standalone mode

Or you can use this

```
window.location = url(your Url);
```

Answer (score -10):

There you go! (if you still need it)

```
<script>
    if(window.navigator.standalone === true) 
     document.write('Standalone');
    else
     document.write('Web browser');
</script>
```

R.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: Well that's a 2012 message but fair enough! This code tests if the web engine is used in standalone mode or not. AFAIK only supported by iOS