# iPhone window.open(url, '_blank') does not open links in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, html, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm sending users to some .pdfs in a standalone web app (saved to home page, no PhoneGap) on iPhone/iPad. With `window.open(url, '_blank');` these documents open on top of the web app and since there is no back button there is no way to get back. Can I open these in a new window in JavaScript, or do I just need to use a real `a href`?

Comment: It is possible with javascript; see top-voted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do it using JavaScript, but doing it with an anchor tag would be much easier. All you have to do is add a "target="_blank" attribute to the anchor tag and it should work:

`<a href="https://www.pdflink.com" rel="PDF link" target="_blank">Link Text</a>`